# How does a server handle multiple users

Tags: php, ajax

I have a question in my mind that if answered can solve my problem. 
How does server handle multiple user request for PHP scripts?

For example, if a user open a page that access a PHP script using ajax request, and for instance that PHP script has a long process ( actually very long ) and another more user open the same page in other machines, and another more and more user.

Does the process in PHP needed to be finished first before the second user who access to the script can be handled or will they be handled in parallel way the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The web server, say Apache, will launch a new independent PHP process for every request. There may be several instances of PHP executing the same script independently of each other running simultaneously. They do not wait for each other* nor do they interfere with each other**.

<sub>* If they are trying to access shared, locked resources simultaneously, they may have to wait for each other. Say, files or sessions.</sub>
<sub>** Unless of course they modify some external resource (say files or database records) in a way where they interfere.</sub>